# overwrite excel file without popup in C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

The following piece of code to save an excel file still throws a pop up box asking if I should overwrite the existing file. How can I auto overwrite the existing file without the popup being thrown?

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Temp\csharp-Excel.xls"
                                  , XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal
                                  , misValue
                                  , misValue
                                  , misValue
                                  , misValue
                                  , XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive
                                  , XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
                                  , misValue
                                  , misValue
                                  , misValue
                                  , misValue);
```

Comment: I am not sure of your circumstances because `SaveAs` should rather be used on a file that has not been saved yet. If you are working with a file that has already been saved(meaning you are working on an existing file) you should rather use the [`Workbook.Save` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197585(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: My circumstances is to either create a new file or overwrite the existing file if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off the `DisplayAlerts` property on the application object. For example:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

As @Degustaf has pointed out: It is important to run `excel.DisplayAlerts = True` after your `SaveAs` code runs.

Also, you can use `System.IO.File.Exist()` to check if that file exists and then just delete it with `File.Delete`.

For example:

```
var fileName = @"C:\Temp\csharp-Excel.xls";
if (File.Exists(fileName)) File.Delete(fileName);
```

This will ensure that there is no file of the same name, so you can overwrite it without a prompt.

Comment: It is important to run `excel.DisplayAlerts = True` after your `SaveAs` code runs.

Comment: @Degustaf ok, thanks. I have added that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I chose option 2 to delete the file. I thought "XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges" parameter would overwrite the file.

Comment: @vba4all You do it before you create the file.